# ReferenceError: prompt is not defined . Even after installing prompt-sync

Tags: javascript, node.js

**ReferenceError: prompt is not defined**

i am a beginner in js ,started recently.when i type my first starting program in javascript it is showing "ReferenceError: prompt is not defined"

```
var fname = prompt("enter ur first name: ")
var lname = prompt("enter ur last name: ")

console.log("ur full name is",fname,lname)
```

it is showing the out put as

```
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\VS Code\VS Code programs\.js\test.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

i even installed prompt-sync,node.js and npm latest version but it didn't work out .

then my friend suggested me to write the js program like this,

```
**const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();**

var fname = prompt("enter ur first name: ")
var lname = prompt("enter ur last name: ")

console.log("ur full name is",fname,lname)
```

then its showing the output
but i want to know that is there any other solution other the typing the code
`const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();`
in every program i write

Comment: "is there any other solution other the typing the code" -- no

Answer (score -1):

Node.js does not have a global variable named `prompt` (unlike [browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)).

If you want a function named `prompt` then you have to define one.

Using the third-party `prompt-sync` module is one way to do that.

You can't just do nothing and have `prompt` exist.

Comment: is there any other way to get input from users other than using prompt-sync or prompt command